# Hibernate Query API - criteria on property of a key in map

Tags: java, hibernate3

Let's say I have such model:

```
public class ProjectModel {
        ...
        private Map<UserModel, ProjectUserRelations> usersRelations = new HashMap<UserModel, ProjectUserRelations>();
}
```

mapped in hbm like this:

```
...
<map name="usersRelations" cascade="save-update" table="PROJECT_MEMBERS">
    <key column="project_id" />
    <map-key-many-to-many column="user_id" class="UserModel"/>
    <many-to-many column="properties_id" class="ProjectUserRelations"/>
</map>
...
```

How can I user Hibernate Criteria to list projects that have given user?
I tried with this:

Criteria hbCriteria = session.createCriteria(ProjectModel.class);

```
if(criteria.getUserId() != null) {
    hbCriteria.createCriteria("usersRelations").add(Restrictions.eq("userId", criteria.getUserId()));
}
```

Of course user is mapped:

```
<class name="UserModel"
    table="USER">
    <id name="objectId" column="objectId" type="java.lang.Long">
</class>
```

When using current implementation a get:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: usersRelations.objectId of: ProjectModel
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do (setting up a criteria on key property of map that's modelled as many-to-many) is achievable using hibernate criteria API.

Have you tried:

```
hbCriteria.createCriteria("usersRelations").add(Restrictions.eq("userModel.userId", criteria.getUserId()));
```

?

Comment: No, what you suggested is setting criteria on property of **value** of a Map, I want to set criteria on property of **key** of a Map

Comment: I thought UserModel is the key in your map? You want to find all user relations that have a specific UserModel, right?

Comment: yes, exactly. But what you have written is criteria on property named "userModel" in "usersRelations" - in values. At least this is what hibernate says in exception when I copy-pasted this. And I have no reason not to believe him :)